# Trying to get cypress to click on an element that it can't see

Tags: cypress

I have been trying too manipulate a form, for some reason Cypress when I use the selector tool it just highlights the whole form rather than just the element I need.

I have isolated one of the fields I need to click on, this is the element:

Also if i copy the selector I get:

> #input-7

However, if i try and cy.get the above selector I get this error:

Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: [id="input-7"], but never found it.

Does anyone know what I can do?

Comment: Could you share your cypress code? Otherwise it is hard to follow

Comment: Try `.click({force:true})` This will click the button if it is hidden from the DOM

Answer (score 0):

For forms I usually do smth like this:

```
cy.get('form').within( () => {
    cy.get('input[formControlName*=\'userName\']').type('Peter')
})
```

Maybe also you have the problem of being in a within loop. Then you can try to add the `{withinSubject: null}` like so:

```
cy.get('#input-7', {withinSubject: null})
```

Note that I used the `#` instead of `id=`